# Can I Uninstall Exchange 2003 without the CD?

Tags: exchange-2003

Is there a way to uninstall Exchange 2003 without the cd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not cleanly. You can go thru the tedious [How to remove Exchange Server 2003 from your computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833396) procedure. I wouldn't recommend doing that, if at all possible.

If you're not in a hurry, consider getting your hands on a copy of the CD and doing the uninstall that way.